# NPM v8.17.0 and upper version is known not to run on Node.js v18.16.0 in AIX 7.2 TL5

Tags: node.js, npm, aix

I am facing the Issue that when we trigger the "**npm stop**" from Script file it getting an error
**node --expose_gc ./lib/stop.js: --:  not found**
The Node version I am using is **v18.16.0**, NPM version **v8.17.0 and upper version**

And also I am facing issue with node **v18.16.0**, NPM version **v9.5.1** the npm start is triggering from script file but npm stop is not triggering. This node version of 18.16.0, I am working on Linux system with AIX 7.2. We have tried downgrade the npm version to v8.11.0 it working.
Till npm v8.16 it working as accepted but after npm v8.17.0 facing error **node --expose_gc ./lib/stop.js: --:  not found**

I have tried to downgrade the NPM version

Comment: Share the full relevant line in `package.json` and full output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.